# How to filter out DEPRECATED || OBSOLETE images using filter field Google Cloud Compute API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So, I am trying to get images that are not **DEPRECATED** or **OBSOLETE**. I am using API which is available in the docs. What I have tried already is putting `(deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED")` this works but it shows OBSOLETE ones in the response. My next attempt was trying the request with following filter `(deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED") OR (deprecated.state != "OBSOLETE")`. But for some unknown reason it still returns OBSOLETE ones. Another idea was just filter those images which does not have deprecated.state field. But I didn't succeed to create such filter.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list the link to test

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **AND** your query, because you only want images which are not *OBSOLETE* **AND** not *DEPRECATED*.

```
(deprecated.state != "OBSOLETE") AND (deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED")
```

or this, as AND is implicit:

```
(deprecated.state != "OBSOLETE") (deprecated.state != "DEPRECATED")
```

Tested right now with the API Explorer on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/list.